# Extra Polyline shows on the Map between any two markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I have one issue regarding `Google Map` and this issue is also on the website that is using it. I am placing `two markers` and a route in between these markers, using the `latitude` and `longitude` that I gather when I move, run or drive between these two locations.

Issue is that an extra `poly-line` drawn between any `marker` that is placed on the `map`. This is a straight line denoting shortest distance between two `markers`, that I do not know where it is coming from.

This is an unwanted `poly-line` that I wish to remove. While on my device I do not see this `line`, my client and my `web-site` developer reports that this `poly-line` is drawn automatically in the map, where there is no code written for it.

Snap shot of `map` that I have shared on web from my `application` on `Android device`:

[image: Snap shot of map that I have shared on web from my application on Android device]

Snap shot of `map` that my client has shared on web from my `application` on some other `Android` device:

[image: Snap shot of map that my client has shared on web from my application on some other Android device]

This could be device specific, so I have requested device information from my client.

This is the code I am using:

```
TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.markers)));
TP1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint1).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.markers)));
if (polyLineOptions != null) {
    googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
}
```

Here `polyLineOptions` is an `array` of `latitudes` and `longitudes`. While sending to the server I send these `latitudes` and `longitudes` in the form of `JSON`.

While receiving these `latitudes` and `longitudes` from the server, I get them in the form of similar `JSON` which I use to convert into the `array` of `latitudes` and `longitudes` for the same `running activity` into `googleMap.addPolyline` method. As I checked on our side, the issue is not happening.

Please let us know there is a way to remove this poly-line, if it reproduces at your end?

Comment: Could you share the code used for generating the PolyLine?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `polyLineOptions`. The reason I asked is because it seems that the start point is getting added to the list at the end.

Comment: It could happen, but when I use my device, I never get the last poly-line, but my client and server end developer seldom gets the last poly-line. My developer says that it is added automatically by the map interface. We both are using this API separately (independently) in app and server. We both have tried to remove it. Any two markers are selected at random and this line is drawn between them.

Comment: Also in that case of adding first poly-line in the last may show the markers in the same place, which is not happening. Also no poly-line is added after adding the marker in the code.